# How to debug proxy data in browser's console?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

with Vuejs3 app I make output of var :

```
  console.log('+++FOUND getForumOrderingLabelsByForumCategoryId.value::')
  console.log(getForumOrderingLabelsByForumCategoryId.value)
  formSelectionOrdering.value = ''
  nextForumOrderingLabel.forumsList.map((nextForumListItem /*, index */) => {
    console.log('nextForumListItem::')
    console.log(nextForumListItem)
```

and got structured output : https://prnt.sc/vyscb7

But that is array of data I receive from backendpoint with axios
To see real values of the vars I have to click in browser's console many times...

Are there some wrapping functions using in console I can see real values  at once?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just use `JSON.stringify(nextForumListItem, null, 2)`.